# NSPopupButton with color well

Tags: cocoa, nspopupbutton, nscontrol, nscolorwell

Some of the color selection buttons in the Xcode details panels are a NSPopupButton with a color well. It looks something like a segmented control/popup button.

Placing a standard color well and standard popup button next to each other doesn't have the same look. Also, the menu wouldn't cover the color well in this case. The popup image (two triangles) is not readily available for a custom control either.

Anyone tried to make a similar control before? Any hints on how to make it?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: This control is (at this moment) not available. You could try to make something yourself by overriding the button and diving into its internals. Overriding some of the (drawing) functions of NSButton can get you a close approximation.